# Android Intent Whatsapp

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp

Attempting via Android intent, to share to Whatsapp, multiple images each with different text.
Is there a doc outlining how Whatsapp maps android's intent secondary attributes? specifically the extras? i.e. to what intent attribute would you add the arrayList of differing text for each image.

Comment: You should be checking WhatsApp's faq page.

Comment: I have, it's not developer focus to the above. Do you have a more specific resource to share?